# Bash echo is changing two spaces into tabulator if string contains this *,*

Tags: bash, oracle, plsql, echo

I have a bash script that takes data from an Oracle database and prints them. (my script is bit more complicated then that but I cut the parts that are not important is this case).

So in Oracle DB I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE spacetest (
col1 varchar2(20),
col2 varchar2(100)
);
INSERT INTO spacetest values('TEST','BETWEEN  TWOSPACES');
commit;
```

Here I have this string 'BETWEEN  TWOSPACES' where I literally have two space, ASCII 32[image]

If I query the table I have two spaces in the string.

Now if I run a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
  lsout=$(sqlplus -S /NOLOG <<EOF
set heading off termout off pagesize 0 echo off
conn user/password@//localhost:1521/localdatabase
SELECT * FROM spacetest;
select COL1 || '*,*' || COL2 || '#@' combined FROM SPACETEST;
select COL1 || '*,' ||  COL2 || '#@' combined FROM SPACETEST;
select COL1 || ',*' ||  COL2 || '#@' combined FROM SPACETEST;
select COL1 || '**' ||  COL2 || '#@' combined FROM SPACETEST;
select COL1 || '°,#' ||  COL2 || '#@' combined FROM SPACETEST;
select COL1 || '*#*' || COL2 || '#@' combined FROM SPACETEST;
exit
EOF
)
echo "$lsout" | od -c

echo done
```

Those containing `*,*` or `#,#` have the spaces in the string converted into tabulators. This behavior doesn't occur in database, there all the results contains two spaces.
[image]

Any idea for this behavior?

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

$echo "${BASH_VERSION}" 
4.2.46(2)-release
```

**NOTE:** I edited my former question, because I was able to simplify it and cut the pl/sql part of it.

Comment: I don't seen any obvious problems (though this seems far from a [mcve]), but what happens if you quote the here-doc delimiter? `lsout=$(sqlplus -S /NOLOG <<'EOF'`

Comment: @chepner it doesn't seem to have any effect at all

Comment: Nothing in the bash part should be converting spaces to tab characters, so I suspect the problem is somewhere else (maybe how the environment you're using handles the script's output?). Try using `echo "$lsout" | od -c` at the end of the script to see what the exact characters are from within the script (it'll show tab as "`\t`"). If it shows as a tab there, try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script to get an execution trace as it runs, and see what that shows.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I did it and also edited my question, since I was able to narrow down the case

Comment: From that test, it looks like something the `sqlplus` command is doing in its output. You can double-check this by copying its output directly to a file with `lsout=$(sqlplus -S /NOLOG <<EOF | tee sqloutput.txt`, and then using `od -c` or something similar on the `sqloutput.txt` file. As for *why* `sqlplus` would do this, I have no idea.

Comment: Try adding `SET TAB OFF` in the SQL commands. The documentation is not entirely clear to me (understatement), but that might do it...

Comment: @GordonDavisson you are right, it was the sqlplus doing it, I ran the script via sqlplus directly and the switch to tabulators was already there. I was previously trying the sql code via SQL Developer and no such thing occurred there. Also the set tab off does the job. Thanks for the resolving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs were being inserted by the `sqlplus` command, and the solution was to add `SET TAB OFF` to the SQL commands. I found this in the [Oracle SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm):

> **SET TAB {ON|OFF}**
> SET TAB is not supported in *i*SQL*Plus
> Determines how SQL*Plus formats white space in terminal output. OFF uses spaces to format white space in the output. ON uses the TAB character. TAB settings are every eight characters. The default value for TAB is system dependent.

Apparently the default value is OFF in SQL Developer, but ON in the command-line `sqlplus` program. I'm still not clear why the tab conversion only happened for some outputs.